# why does facebook not load my home.php page but only the home.html page

Tags: php

i have my own website but when i make a link on face book using the html file then it loads but when i use a PHP file it does not load the Facebook link
also why does not work on your host home page only on other pages

Comment: Might be *goblins*, who knows.

Comment: Please, provides so examples, I don't understand you question.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is not such a good idea to have more than 1 index.* script on a website.

Things just get confusing.

Personally I always remove all index.* scripts EXCEPT the index.php script.

Then you have to set the .htaccess script (if you are allowed to) to send any unresolvable requests to index.php (basic "friendly URL" practice).